# Use HTTP.sys to enable windows authentication #Error: read ECONNRESET ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, windows-authentication, http.sys

I want to use Http.sys to enable windows authentication and use POSTman to send GET request.
I already enter my computer's account and password,but POSTman told me this error.
Having no idea what happened,somebody can tell me the reason?
[Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#httpsys)
**UPDATE**
[My Purpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptR1V.jpg)
**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAuthentication(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "webwinauth", Version = "v1" });
            });
}

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "webwinauth v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseHttpSys(options =>
                    {
                        options.Authentication.Schemes = 
                            AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | 
                            AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                        options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                    });;
                });
```

**POSTman**
[Setting about NTLM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUnpw.png)
**ERROR**
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmy5F.png)

Comment: You cannot use `Http.sys` with `asp.net core`  its not compatible with the `ASP.NET Core Module` and can't be used with IIS or IIS Express.

Comment: Hello Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Http.sys` with `asp.net core`  its not compatible with the `ASP.NET Core Module` and can't be used with IIS or IIS Express. You could have a look [here if offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

[image]

Note: You could also have a look [offical reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-the-aspnet-core-app-to-use-httpsys)

> ***`Update:`*** Complete official sample you can [download from here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Identity)

Hope it would help you.

Comment: Hi,I update my question,the picture is my teammate show me. I want to do the same thing,but I forgot the whole setting steps. I wish you can help me,thanks!

Comment: Well, you could have a look the [complete steps here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I have updated the identity server complete example for you, you can get from the given link.